# SunRSASign Provider for IBM sdk

Tags: java, sdk, cryptography, websphere, rsa

I'm trying to run the following code on both Oracle 1.7 and IBM 1.7 JDK.

```
KeyPairGenerator serverKpairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        serverKpairGen.initialize(2048,new SecureRandom());
        KeyPair serverKpair = serverKpairGen.generateKeyPair();


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);

          oos.writeObject(serverKpair);
          oos.close();
          baos.close();

          byte[] serializedObject = baos.toByteArray();
          System.out.println(Base64.encode(serializedObject, false, false).length());
```

Oracle by-default uses SunRsaSign as its default-provider for RSA algorithm and where IBM uses IBMJCE

IBMJCE gives keypair of length 5100 bytes and Oracle generates keypair length of nearly 2800 bytes .

I've tried to set SunJce as a provider but it doesn't support RSA algorithm.

Is there anyway in IBM SDK 1.6 or 1.7 to set SunRSASign as a provider? I observed SunRSASign is a part of rt.jar in Oracle java. **Can we reduce the ServerKey pair size in IBM java to < 4000 bytes ?**

Can we get a key-size length in IBM sdk which is similar to Oracle jdk? Is there any other default provider in IBM which gives less key-size with RSA2048.

Comment: Don't use the `Serializable` interface to persist a keypair. Instead, persist to a PKCS12 `KeyStore`. Alternatively, persist the PublicKey and PrivateKey components separately using their `.getEncoded()` methods.

Comment: Thanks @JamesKPolk. Your suggestion really worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

James already gave most of the answer in a comment: use a PKCS#12 key store for the private key. This is more secure than storing it unprotected.

You can use `getEncoded` to get an encoding of the public / private keys. This encoding contains a length already, but you may want to precede it with a 4 byte length encoding - an encoded integer - none-the-less. So your serialization would take two steps.

For Java's `SunRSASign` it returns a `SubjectKeyIdentifier` for the public key and an inner PKCS#8 structure for the private key. Although `getEncoded` is not standardized (a big mistake in my opinion, but OK) most other providers will follow Sun / Oracle's lead anyway.

Whatever road the providers take for `getEncoded`:

1. both structures are well defined and standardized and
2. they will be easier to parse then a provider specific object serialization;
3. finally, they will also be much smaller than the structures you're currently handling.

You can use a `KeyFactory` created using `getInstance("RSA")` to retrieve the keys back. The key specs should be delivered using `X509EncodedKeySpec` for the SubjectPublicKey and `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` for the PKCS#8 encoded private key.